# Create a folder about an item with Microsoft Graph Sharepoint

Tags: api, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

How do I create a folder on my list? I can create a file but I can't define a type.
Should I define a type column? But how can I create a column with a type characteristic?
I am using Graph Explorer to build and want to use PHP after for my Laravel website.

Thank you for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new list with a document library as a template. Then you will have a new drive in the root of your site where you can create a folder.

Comment: Thanks you for your comment but i find my solution

Comment: That's great! Best regards

Answer (score 0):

After testing and testing, i find my request.

If it can help someone :

**POST** `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/children`

site-id is composed about two ID, site-id and subsite-id.

To find your site-id :
**GET** `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root`

My subsite-id is my groupsite id, you can find him on :
**GET** `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{sites-id}/lists?search=doc`

After i did a request to find {item-id} :
**GET** `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/root:/test`

And to end :
**POST** `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/children`